# cx_oracle: write sql that use all the bind variables

Tags: sql, python-3.x, oracle11g, cx-oracle

for my code to be generic I need to rewrite all my sql queries in such a way that it uses all the bind variables. Currently If some bind variables passed in the 
cx_Oracle.execute(sql,params) does not exist in the sql query I am getting error

```
ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
```

Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you mean -- but you can use the cursor.bindnames() function to determine all of the bind variables.